# Database Engine recovery handle failed SQl server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

My first question in this forum. When I try to install SQL 2008 r2 on my Win 7 32 bit system, I get the following error " Wait on database engine recovery handle failed." Can someone help I me to get out of this. I can post the error log if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome...most probably you are facing the problem which I had face few months back. Here is the solution

1) Un-install the SQLserver

2) Re-install it back with following changes

In the server configuration section, I change the account name details to "NT AUTHORITY/LOCALSERVICE" (during the installation process)

If this does not help post the error log